# What would be the correct html element for document author?

Tags: seo, html, xhtml

Which html element should be used when writing out the author of an html document, with regards to semantics, SEO and so forth?

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the meta tag like Tom Gullen suggested, but then the only way to find out the author is to check the source of the page, since browsers don't tell you. Most people do not know how to do that.

If you want to make it clear to all visitors who wrote the page's content, put the author's name direct on the page. There is no special element for that so just use `p`, `span` or `div`, whichever is appriprite.

You may also like to take a look at the [hAtom](http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom) and [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) microformats, which use semantic classes to describe entities like articles and people.

Finally just to point out - the author is irrelevant for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

```
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="George Costanza, gcostanza@vandalayindustries.com">
```

Although usage of this is questionably useless.  But it wont do any harm either way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, if the author info is for easy human consumption, use microformats. the Author metatag is only ever seen by people checking out other people's code!